# How to setup bcache?

Tags: ssd, gparted, bcache

I've tried to set up bcache in Ubuntu 14.04 with a fresh install and an empty `/home` partition (`/dev/sdb2`) as a backing device. I have a running system on my SSD and I'd like to use its `/dev/sda2` partition to cache my `/home`
.
I've always managed to sort my ubuntu problems out from forums but I'm struggling to understand the basics here and need help:

1. What account do I need to be logged in when I set up bcache in the first place? Obviously the user created during install on `/dev/sdb2` has to be logged out for `/home` to be unmounted, so I set up a temporary user account on a separate partition to do it. This seems too clumsy already.
2. `make-bcache -B` and `-C` both tell me that there are non-bcache superblocks on the device so I did `sudo wipefs -a` on both of the devices.
   The partitions then appear as unformatted without an UUID in GParted. Is this normal?
3. If so, what happens to fstab and `/home` at boot? Do I need to use bcache's UUID in fstab? I did but the system didn't find the `/home` partition upon next boot.
4. Both `echo /dev/sdb2 > /sys/fs/bcache/register` and `echo /dev/sda2 > /sys/fs/bcache/register` return 'Permission denied' messages; as I understand `/sys` cannot be written to.

   So  `echo /dev/sdb2 | sudo tee /sys/fs/bcache/register` seems to have worked.

Can someone verify this is the proper way to do it in Ubuntu?

I seem to have managed to create, register and attach the backing drive but according to the `tail /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/stats_total/*`  I only have bypassed data.
My whole setup is quite a mess now so any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tested it? Appears that you know the "how-to", what you need to know?

Comment: I tested it as above and I'm getting cache hits, misses and bypasses. Trouble is my backing device that is supposed to be my home partition is not mounted as home at startup but as a separate drive. So my /home is a folder on / at the moment and I'm testing bcache by copying files onto the backing device and accessing them. 
I was messing with fstab which was probably a mistake and I don't have a valid UUID for my /home partition now if that makes any sense..
What I need is an idiot-proof walk-through specifically for ubuntu.

Comment: OK, I messed up fstab and /home had the wrong UUID.
It seems to work now.
I would still be interested in how exactly is bcache supposed to be set up: from temporary user account, live CD/USB, or other?

Answer (score 9):

With Ubuntu 15.10, alex's answer is no longer correct. The `initramfs` image is locked in the installer and will not be automatically re-generated when the system is installed. Thus one will have a `bcache` installation, but it won't be able to boot. I've written a more [verbose description of the following process elsewhere](http://www.kloppenborg.net/blog/2016/02/17/installing-ubuntu-1510-with-bcache-support); however, here are the basics:

#### 1. Partitioning

Boot into the Ubuntu live-cd and create the following partition scheme with `fdisk` or `gparted`. Assuming `/dev/sda` is your SSD and `/dev/sdb` is your HDD:

```
/dev/sda1 - 1024 MB, EXT4, used for /boot (grub/grub2 doesn't support bcache)
/dev/sda2 - any format, for cache
/dev/sdb1 - EFI partition (if your machine needs it)
/dev/sdb2 - swap
/dev/sdb3 - any format, backing partition
```

#### 2. Create the bcache device

Open up the terminal, wipe the file systems on the backing and caching device:

```
sudo wipefs -a /dev/sda2
sudo wifefs -a /dev/sdb3
```

Install `bcache-tools` and create the `bcache` device:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcache-tools
sudo make-bcache -B /dev/sdb3 -C /dev/sda2
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/bcache0
```

#### 3. Install Ubuntu

Install the operating system using the custom partitioner as follows:

```
/dev/bcache0 - format EXT4, use as /
/dev/sda1    - format EXT4, use as /boot
/dev/sdb1    - EFI partition (if your machine needs it)
/dev/sdb2    - swap
```

*DO NOT REBOOT* after the installer completes!

#### 4. Install bcache on the new installation

Using a `chroot` we install `bcache-tools` on the new installation.
Setup the environment and enable DNS resolution

```
sudo mount /dev/bcache0 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

For Ubuntu 17.10 or newer you also need to copy over the resolv.conf file
so DNS resolution works within the `chroot` environment.

```
sudo mv /mnt/etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf.backup
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
```

Enter into the `chroot` and do the installation

```
sudo chroot /mnt
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcache-tools
```

During the installation you should notice the `initramfs` is re-generated and installed to the (`chroot`-ed) `/boot` partition.

#### 5. Cleanup

Cleanly dismount the filesystem and reboot.

```
exit
sudo mv /mnt/etc/resolv.conf.backup /mnt/etc/resolv.conf # for 17.10+ only
sudo umount /mnt/sys
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt/boot
sudo umount /mnt
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Five years later and this still works well. Thanks @bklppenborg for updating the instructions for 20.04: https://www.kloppenborg.net/blog/2020/05/22/installing-ubuntu-20-04-with-bcache

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about this post. I updated it to include the resolv.conf instructions for Ubuntu 17.10+.

Answer (score 2):

After some trial and error I've arrived at the following solution for a **clean install:**

- Partition the HDD the way you like (assuming `/dev/sdb2` is the space you want for your `/home`).
- `# apt-get install bcache-tools`
- `# make-bcache -B /dev/sdb2 -C /dev/sda2`  (This creates `/dev/bcache0`, but the UI installer can't use it yet.)
- `# mkfs.ext4 /dev/bcache0`  (This makes the installer see a "partition /dev/bcache0" under "device /dev/bcache0" and allows you to use it as "/home" during installation.)
- Run the installer as usual, be sure to select advanced disk partition options.
- The installer creates `initrd` image with the `bcache` kernel module included and loaded due to that we've installed `bcache-tools` earlier, so after reboot it just works.
- After booting the installed system, install `bcache-tools` once again, so that further updates don't cripple the boot process by omitting the necessary bcache kernel module from initrd image.

Comment: I went without bcache in the end because I needed cacheing for both Ubuntu and Windows in a double-boot configuration plus I access my drives from another system as well. So I decided cacheing is just not suitable for this PC. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I too tried and failed many times till I found these instructions:
http://www.wdong.org/wordpress/blog/2014/05/28/installing-ubuntu-14-04-to-bcache/

They sound somewhat hairy but this is probably the only feasible way to get bcache going, at least until bcache becomes part of the ubuntu installer.

The only curious omission in the instructions is the very last stage.

After you've done everything, look up the UUID of the cache set in /sys/fs/bcache and do this:

```
echo <UUID> > /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/attach
```

If you'd like to enable writeback mode (which I'd strongly recommend):

```
echo writeback > /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/cache_mode
```

catting various files in `/sys/block/bcache0/bcache/` will tell you all about how the cache is running. I set up my system using these instructions on July 26th this year and everything is running perfectly since. `cat /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/stats_total/cache_hit_ratio` shows a highly satisfactory 88 per cent and subjectively, the machine feels like an all-SSD setup.