# Optimize Hybrid Hard Drive & 8 GB SSD for Ubuntu

Tags: ssd

How do i set up Ubuntu to ultilize the SSD partiton like Windows does?

Windows uses the 8GB partition for frequent applications and for quick stand-by mode.

Since 8GB is pretty small for the root folder to be on the SSD partition, how do I set up this partition for Ubuntu to do the same thing as Windows does?

The reason I ask is because Ubuntu Mate is pretty slow when resuming from the "suspend" state.

Laptop: Samsung Chronos 7 15.6" (2012 Edition)

OS: Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Physical Drives: Hybrid 1TB Hard Drive/Sandisk 8GB SSD

RAM: 8 GB

Processor: ivy bridge 2.4 GHz i7 processor with turboboost up to 3.1 GHz

Comment: One of the options would be using bcache. Maybe  http://askubuntu.com/questions/523817/how-to-setup-bcache and http://c0rp.kz/migrate-existing-system-to-bcache/ may help you.